# Change WIA scanner source in powershell script

Tags: powershell, wia

So i am using a script to automate scanning, everything is good except that my scanner always uses the flatbed for scanning and I can't seem to change the source to Feeder. Here is the code i'm using

```
# Create object to access the scanner

$deviceManager = new-object -ComObject WIA.DeviceManager
$device = $deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(1).Connect()
# Create object to access the scanned image later
$imageProcess = new-object -ComObject WIA.ImageProcess

# Store file format GUID strings
$wiaFormatBMP  = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
$wiaFormatPNG  = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
$wiaFormatGIF  = "{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
$wiaFormatJPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
$wiaFormatTIFF = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

# Scan the image from scanner as BMP
foreach ($item in $device.Items) {
    $image = $item.Transfer() 
}

# set type to JPEG and quality/compression level
$imageProcess.Filters.Add($imageProcess.FilterInfos.Item("Convert").FilterID)
$imageProcess.Filters.Item(1).Properties.Item("FormatID").Value = $wiaFormatJPEG
$imageProcess.Filters.Item(1).Properties.Item("Quality").Value = 5
$image = $imageProcess.Apply($image)

# Build filepath from desktop path and filename 'Scan 0'
$filename = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Scan {0}.jpg"

# If a file named 'Scan 0' already exists, increment the index as long as needed
$index = 0
while (test-path ($filename -f $index)) {[void](++$index)}
$filename = $filename -f $index

# Save image to 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Scan {x}'
$image.SaveFile($filename)

# Show image 
& $filename
```

I only need to change the scanner source and then save all the images.

Comment: Where you are assigning to `$device`, how do you know that you have selected the intended device?

Comment: I don't actually. But it seems to choose the intended scanner. Only the source of the scanner is Flatbed somehow and I need to change that to Feeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research and experiments. I finally made it work.

```
foreach($prop in $device.Properties){
    if( $prop.Name -eq "Document Handling Select"){
        $prop.Value=1
    }
}
```

But this still only gave me 1 image so i had to use a while loop over all the code i gave before. Works perfect now!